# PHP: how to prevent domain from being appended to the server-FQDN by nslookup using gethostbyname()

Tags: php

I am using the following code to check to see if the dns entry exists for a domain (basically to validate the domain is real)...

```
$sdip = gethostbyname("www.nonexistancedomainsdlkmsaldsa.com.");
$sddomain = gethostbyaddr($sdip);
print "IP: $sdip\n";
print "Domain: $sddomain\n";
```

It is returning....IP: 67.215.65.132 Domain: hit-nxdomain.opendns.com

So I am assuming that it is in fact searching for www.nonexistancedomainsdlkmsaldsa.com.myhostname.com (not exactly sure on this).

I read the article on php.net about adding a `.` following the domain, so I tried this and it didn't change anything.  Anyone understand why I'm getting this?  Basically, here is what I am trying to do...

User enters domain name (no http/https)....it checks to see if domain exists, if it does, it continues my script, if it does not exist, it fails with an error message.

I want them to be able to enter ANY valid domain name and it check it.  So any other solutions would be helpful if there is anything better.  Basically I am using this as a validation to see if domain name exists.

I would also (if at all possible), like to find out how to check regexp for
sub.subdomain.domain.tld where sub and subdomain are not required (basically to see if format is a valid format).  I have searched stackoverflow, but they don't get into the detail I need to allow sub.subdomain but not require them.

article on php.net:

> If you do a gethostbyname() and there is no trailing dot after a
>   domainname that does not resolve, this domainname will ultimately be
>   appended to the server-FQDN by nslookup.
>
> So if you do a lookup for nonexistentdomainname.be your server may
>   return the ip for nonexistentdomainname.be.yourhostname.com, which is
>   the server-ip.
>
> To avoid this behaviour, just add a trailing dot to the domainname;
>   i.e. gethostbyname('nonexistentdomainname.be.')

### EDIT

it isn't in fact returning my server IP (i overlooked that).  So I don't know if that article is relevant to this problem or not.  I will leave it just in case it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using OpenDNS as your DNS server. When you query OpenDNS for a non-existent domain, they will redirect you to one of their own "search result" pages/servers. This is specifically for OpenDNS, other DNS servers should not behave this way and correctly return no result.

Comment: 1) Any Idea how I change this?  2) Is there a better way of doing what I'm doing with searching for valid domain.  3) Any idea on how to do the regexp format I need?

Comment: 1) Don't use OpenDNS *or* check whether you're getting a *.opendns.com domain back. 2) I'd be doing more low-level DNS queries by hand and parse the results; can't advise on a good PHP way of doing it, but play around with `dig` on the command line (Linux/UNIX, don't know about Windows). 3) I'm unclear what you want there.

Comment: basically, I am trying to find an expression that will check any entry that is put in to see if it is a valid format for a domain url.  This includes domain.tld, subdomain.tld, sub.subdomain.tld ect. ect. ect.  I need to basically just see if its the right format no matter what is put in.  I am using this in conjunction with what I am trying to do with gethostbyname

Comment: `parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST)` - don't reinvent the wheel. :-3

Comment: `$domain = "http://example"; echo parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);` returns example as the url host, which isn't a valid domain.  So please tell me how this works with what I am referring to?  It doesn't.  Which is why I need the correct regex to VALIDATE if it is a correct domain (regular expression) to check ALL possibilites, and not just top level domains (domain.com)

Comment: `example` *is* a perfectly valid domain name. It may not be registered, but it's technically valid. If you want to further narrow it down to domains which have at least one `.` in them, do a check for `/.+\..+/`. If it passes both tests it should be a pretty valid domain name.

Comment: ahh..i see what you did there.  thanks for the info!